# display:block not working on max-width

Tags: css

I am trying to hide a div when the size of the screen is below a certain number of pixels :

```
<div id="messageLeftToto" style="width:450px;height:570px;border:4px solid #000;box-sizing:border-box;display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 110px;">
</div>

 <style>
     @media (max-width :960px) {#messageLeftToto {display:none}
 </style>
```

but the element is always visible!

Comment: Style inside body tag won't work. (assuming from location of div, which should be in body.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak: styles located in `body` are applied too, of course.

Comment: My bad then, I never saw this. But it should still be avoided because css is tricky enough itself, you really shouldn't introduce any more loading/parsing order issues...

Comment: @MarkoGrešak: no, there is no reason why it should be tricky. Just styles could be load longer.

Comment: I meant the rules not working to your expectations, which can happen sometimes. I saw many js problems just because script order and load location, I would expect the same could easily happen with css and it's even harder to find. Also loading styles in body could produce weird page, if the html loads before styles so you'll get plain text page, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use important to override inline style in this case.

```
@media (max-width :960px) {#messageLeftToto {display:none !important}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxm4967s/

Or move inline styles into stylesheet.

```
#messageLeftToto {
    width:450px;
    height:570px;
    border:4px solid #000; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 110px
}

@media (max-width :960px) {#messageLeftToto {display:none }}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxm4967s/1/

Answer (score 4):

**Inline styles always overwrite predefined or included styles** (excluding style defined as `!important` - but avoid `!important` if you can)

A simple rule. This, for example, will work:

```
#messageLeftToto  {
    width: 450px;
    height: 570px;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}
@media (max-width :960px) {
    #messageLeftToto {display:none}
}
```

Its best to not use inline style at all, and if you have to you *can* overwrite using `!important` but then you will have  a stylesheet full of `!important`s. If javascript is changing your styles, it might be best to change the class of the element and add the style to your CSS.